# React Native: Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded Error After Adding Conditional

Tags: ios, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am receiving there error "Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded". After adding a conditional to the navigation file in my code. The stack I am using is React-Native with Expo, Redux, GraphQL and my navigation library is react-navigation. I am working on iOS simulator. This is the code that breaks the
app:

```
//navigations.js     
if (!this.props.user.isAuthenticated) {
          return <AuthenticationScreen />;
        }
```

and this is the entirety of the navigations.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  addNavigationHelpers,
  StackNavigator,
  TabNavigator
} from "react-navigation";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import ExploreScreen from "./screens/ExploreScreen";
import FavoritesScreen from "./screens/FavoritesScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "./screens/ProfileScreen";
import AuthenticationScreen from "./screens/AuthenticationScreen";

import { colors } from "./utils/constants";

const TAB_ICON_SIZE = 20;

const Tabs = TabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        headerTitle: "Saga",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <FontAwesome size={TAB_ICON_SIZE} color={tintColor} name="home" />
        )
      })
    },
    Explore: {
      screen: ExploreScreen,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        headerTitle: "Explore",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <FontAwesome size={TAB_ICON_SIZE} color={tintColor} name="search" />
        )
      })
    },
    Favorites: {
      screen: FavoritesScreen,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        headerTitle: "Favorites",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <FontAwesome
            size={TAB_ICON_SIZE}
            color={tintColor}
            name="file-video-o"
          />
        )
      })
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileScreen,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        headerTitle: "Profile",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <FontAwesome size={TAB_ICON_SIZE} color={tintColor} name="user" />
        )
      })
    }
  },
  {
    lazy: true,
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    swipeEnabled: false,
    tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true,
      showLabel: false,
      activeTintColor: colors.PRIMARY,
      inactiveTintColor: colors.LIGHT_GRAY,
      style: {
        backgroundColor: colors.BASE_GRAY,
        height: 50,
        paddingVertical: 5
      }
    }
  }
);

const AppMainNav = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Tabs
    }
  },
  {
    cardStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#F1F6FA"
    },
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: colors.BASE_GRAY
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: "bold",
        fontSize: 24,
        color: colors.BLUE
      }
    })
  }
);

class AppNavigator extends Component {
  render() {
    const nav = addNavigationHelpers({
      dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
      state: this.props.nav
    });
    if (!this.props.user.isAuthenticated) {
      return <AuthenticationScreen />;
    }
    return <AppMainNav navigation={nav} />;
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
  nav: state.nav,
  user: state.user
}))(AppNavigator);

export const router = AppMainNav.router;
```

[image: iOS Simulator]

For good measure this is the user.js reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  token: null,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  info: null
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I can't see what would be causing an infinite loop.

Update #1

AuthenticationScreen.js (Minus Imports)

```
const Root = styled.View``;

const T = styled.Text``;

class AuthenticationScreen extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <Root>
        <T>AuthenticationScreen</T>
      </Root>
    );
  }
}

export default AuthenticationScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you've isolated the problem to this code...

```
if (!this.props.user.isAuthenticated) {
  return <AuthenticationScreen />;
}
return <AppMainNav navigation={nav} />;
```

And if you remove...

```
if (!this.props.user.isAuthenticated) {
  return <AuthenticationScreen />;
}
```

it works fine, which means <AppMainNav> must be fine. So the infinite loop must be in your <AuthenticationScreen /> code.

Comment: That is correct when you comment that code out the app works fine. That something was broken in <AuthenticationScreen /> was my initial thought but at the moment it's simply setup to render text. Here is the code minus the imports.   `

const Root = styled.View;

const T = styled.Text;

class AuthenticationScreen extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <Root>
        <T>AuthenticationScreen</T>
      </Root>
    );
  }
}

export default AuthenticationScreen;`

Comment: I'd just start isolating it down even further, simplifying it further and further until you identify the specific issue. Comment out the AuthenticationScreen import and replace it with `const AuthenticationScreen = () => &lt;View>&lt;Text>Auth Screen&lt;/Text>&lt;/View>`. If that works, move that into the import file and try it without the styled elements. so on and so forth. Slowly add the complexity until you identify the exact point it breaks.

Comment: I changed the class component to a stateless function as you said and that worked instantly; however, when I added complexity nothing then seemed to break the app. I left that as a band aid since  I was working on other elements of the app. Once it came time to declare `initialState` I was able to render the component as a class. Just as a note for anyone researching the same issue. I also attempted to restart the server and the bundler, erase the simulator of its contents, clear the cache and reset watchman all to no avail. While the app is now working I could never isolate where it breaks.

Comment: Glad it's working now. That's the most  important thing.